# MySQL count distinct where detections occur in three of five receivers for triangulation

Tags: mysql, select

I have a list of radiotransmitter detections, and in order to process the data for triangulation, I need to be sure that the site has had three or more receivers ping out.

The data look like this (except in my real table it is a single DATETIME field):

```
Date    Time    Receiver    Location    Array   Transmitter
4/30/2013   6:14:34 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:17:11 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:19:21 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:20:37 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:22:05 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:23:55 AM  119736   D/s L side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:23:57 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:26:35 AM  119736   D/s L side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:26:37 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:28:52 AM  119736   D/s L side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:28:53 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:30:20 AM  119736   D/s L side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:30:22 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:32:13 AM  119736   D/s L side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:32:15 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:32:16 AM  119740   U/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:34:57 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:34:58 AM  119740   U/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:37:18 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:37:19 AM  119740   U/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:38:55 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:38:56 AM  119740   U/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:41:07 AM  119740   U/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:42:25 AM  119732   D/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:42:26 AM  119740   U/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:43:59 AM  119740   U/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:46:00 AM  119740   U/s R side 1   A69-1303-48591
4/30/2013   6:57:12 AM  113177  U/s Site 1  1   A69-1303-48591
```

As you can see, this fish (A69-1303-48591) hit at least three of the receivers (119732, 119736, 119740, 113177) within an hour, so I can triangulate his movements. Here is my novice attempt at coding something:

```
SELECT * FROM  detections WHERE 
((
recID_Detection = '113177' OR recID_Detection = '119732' OR recID_Detection = '119736'
) AND 
(recID_Detection = '119740' 
))
OR
((
recID_Detection = '113177' OR recID_Detection = '119732' OR recID_Detection = '119740'
) AND 
(recID_Detection = '119736' 
))
OR
((
recID_Detection = '113177' OR recID_Detection = '119736' OR recID_Detection = '119740'
) AND 
(recID_Detection = '119732' 
))
OR
((
recID_Detection = '119732' OR recID_Detection = '119736' OR recID_Detection = '119740'
) AND 
(recID_Detection = '113177' 
))
GROUP BY transmitter
;
```

This code results in an empty set (which it shouldn't) even without the GROUP BY and doesn't even have a time constraint (which it should), so I am sure I've done something improper, but I can't find anything similar to what I want to do in the literature.

Comment: Is there a time span on the 3 pings? For example, 3 pings in an hour is ok, but 3 pings in 5 hours is not returned.

Comment: Hi CharityAbbott, thanks for your comment. The time span is really subjective, so if there is a way to get 3 pings in 5 hours or even 24 hours, I would jump at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not put the names of all of your columns, I assume your column names are `datetime_Detection recID_Detection locID_Detection arrayID_Detection transmitterID_Detection`

If you don't care about the time periods, this will get you started.

```
SELECT transmitterID_Detection,COUNT(DISTINCT recID_Detection) AS countPings 
FROM detections GROUP BY transmitterID_Detection
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT recID_Detection) >= 3
```

Comment: CharityAbbott, you rule! That is exactly what I needed. I didn't know that you could specify >= n for COUNT(DISTINCT). That is so neat! Much adoration and grovelling at your feet! I can try a separate query for the time period.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the first clause:

```
(recID_Detection = '113177' OR recID_Detection = '119732'
    OR recID_Detection = '119736'
) AND (recID_Detection = '119740')
```

Either first part of the clause can be true or the second. There is no way both can be true so this clause is always false. All other clauses are build in a similar way and are always false so you'll never get any match using this query.

Comment: Ah. Yes, that makes sense, zero323. Something looked a little *fishy* with my and/or query. Thank you for the explanation.